# Should I use strings.xml / R.string instead of global String constants (for example for keys in intents)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am wondering if you should use strings.xml instead of global constants. I learned that global variables should be avoided but then again strings.xml are probably not ment to be used like this?

Are there any advantages / disadvantages using one or the other?

I am pretty sure that hardcoded strings like the following is not a good way.

```
putExtra("extraKey", extra);
```

With strings.xml or Constants you have a spellcheck and autocompletion.

A typical line with R.string could look like this.

```
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.first_player_for_intent), firstPlayer);
```

in comparison to the

```
intent.putExtra(MyClass.first_player_for_intent), firstPlayer);
```

If you should use constants, in what class should they be located?

Comment: The concern you have about global variables doesn't apply here.

Global variables should be avoided because it's difficult to reason about their state. Global constants, on the other hand, are very easy to reason about. They have exactly the value they were defined to have, and are never modified.

Comment: fair enough. The question then is where to put the constants but i guess thats up to personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't  use `res/strings.xml` to store constants. You might want to access their value even though you don't have a `context`. Also, your keys don't need to be localized. Regarding the place where you should store it, it is up to you, and imo, it is just a matter of taste. I usually avoid having a dedicated class just for constants, but I declare it where it imo belongs. For instance, if you have a class called `Player`, I would put all the constants `Player` related there.

Comment: +1.  Not to mention the possibility of breaking your app when you decide to add translations for 20 languages.

Answer (score 3):

`strings.xml` is there for a purpose and primary purpose of it is  to support localization.

you should not be overloading this system with constants which are not relevant for localization.

As Blackbelt correctly said you may need to access your constants even without context so that's another reason.